# How to create a scalable calendar service backend for an Android app?

Tags: calendar, cloud, google-calendar-api, scalability

We want to maintain a calendar on our server for each user of an Android app to which the user only has a read-only access.

That could lead to our server creating >1000 calendars per day sometimes.

If we used a Calendar API like Google's, that would mean creating these many calendars per day from our app's service account. But Google currently restricts the number of calendars created per account to 25 / day and they don't even increase this quota for paid Google Apps accounts (I checked).

So what could be a possible solution for us in this case? Do any other platforms have a more scalable API that we could use?

Comment: Is it a requirement that every app user gets a separate Google calendar instance? Will there be access from outside the app? If it's app-only, you could make a calendar instance multi-tenant and do some querying / filtering in the app.

Comment: Having a separate calendar for each user should allow for greater leverage from the API - like finding availability of the user for a new appointment?