# Firebase Calendars

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-calendar-api, google-developers-console

I have been searching all over for this, and I just haven't been able to find a clear answer to my questions.

I'm developing an app for a client and using Firebase as my backend (it's my first time). I need each user account to have it's own calendar.

I will be using the Firebase O-Auth but I don't want my app to see or edit a users auth account calendar (ie: if a google user logs in I don't want to edit their google calendar). I want our database to store a unique calendar for each unique user.

Will the calendar API allow me to do this? The app could potentially have thousands of calendars. I've seen some docs about limits, but it seems like limits on api calls, which I don't have any estimates for at this time.

Would a service account be appropriate for this application?

I've checked these other posts, but they don't quite answer my questions:

[How to create a scalable calendar service backend for an Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30686936/how-to-create-a-scalable-calendar-service-backend-for-an-android-app)

[Google Calendar API - Designed for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42111733/google-calendar-api-designed-for)

Any kind of insight would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand very well what you're asking. Can you reduce it to a single question, like "Can I use API abc to do xyz?" Note that most likely the answer will be "yes" or "no". If you want a more helpful answer, you might want to show what you've already tried, or some pseudo-code of how you're thinking of using the API.

Comment: I actually have several questions that I'm asking here. I thought that by describing what I'm trying to accomplish and what I've read up on before, someone with experience with these services might be able to give me some insight. But I suppose I could rephrase my questions as - Will Firebase allow me to create thousands of calendars? Will the calendar API allow me to make thousands of calendars? Is a service account appropriate to use for making thousands of calendars? Are there limits to how many calendars I can create with these services?

Comment: 1) Firebase has nothing to do with Calendar creation, so imposes no limits. 2) I don't see any quota related to Calendar creation in the Calendar API when I follow this path: https://developers.google.com/calendar/pricing.

Comment: Thank you for the info, Frank. I did see that page in my research, but it doesn't say anything about limits on how many calendars I can create. Am I supposed to assume that if it isn't mentioned that there isn't a limit? How do I know that the limit isn't mentioned somewhere else in the docs and I just missed it? That's why I'm asking these questions. I don't feel comfortable recommending this technology to my client without knowing for sure, and I would look really bad if we somehow hit a limit once the app goes into production. Is there any documentation out there that is more reassuring?

Comment: Derek, did you ever figure out the answer to your question?  If so, could you answer your own question below?  I'm having similar issues with finding the right things to google.  Everywhere seems to be talking about how to edit a user's external calendar and not about creating events in an app that users can subscribe to.

Comment: Sorry Neal, I never did. In fact, I forgot about this question because shortly after posting this the client had a meltdown and the project died. I never got a chance to even try anything. I think I had decided that I would just store the schedule in firebase like any other data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally what we do in this case is create calendars using documents and collections within Firebase.   Here is an example of a calendar app that uses Firebase to store its appointments.  It is written in Flutter, but the backend design for Firebase should be easy to understand.

https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/12067/how-to-work-with-the-firebase-database-and-the-flutter-calendar-for-appointments